# Adding customlink at top navigation?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to add a link at my top navigation i am not getting what is happening at my code:

The module is active and here is the config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <StorePickupLink_PickUpLink>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
        </StorePickupLink_PickUpLink>
    </modules>
    <fronted>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <storepickuplink_pickuplink module="StorePickupLink_PickUpLink">
                <file>storepickuplink_pickuplink.xml</file>
            </storepickuplink_pickuplink>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</fronted>
</config>
```

And here is the layout called by config file

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="StorePickupLink_PickUpLink">
        <name>store_pickup_link</name>
        <path>storepickuplink_pickuplink/index</path>
        <label>Our Stores</label>
        <title>Our Stores</title>
        <position>10</position>
    </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Any idea what is happening with my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things missing / typos in your code:

1. `fronted` -> `frontend`
2. layout is missing a closing tag `</layout>`
3. for correctness you might also want to use `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and `<layout version="0.1.0">`

Comment: Layout version is never evaluated though, correct?

Comment: @philwinkle never investigated but after a quick glance into the code I would say you are correct - I am usually just keeping to how the core layout files are set up.